# How to see the tab bar controller in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

I created a Tab Bar Application in XCode. Then I clicked on MainWindow.xib. In the document window there is a Tab Bar Controller. When you double-click on the window icon, the window is shown. Shouldn't something similar occur if you double-click on the Tab Bar Controller icon?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers don't have any useful visual representation. You can hit Cmd-1 to view the attributes of the object. What would you expect a tab bar controller to look like? If you're talking about viewing the actual tab bar, that should be present in your window, and can be created by dragging a tab bar from the library.

Comment: In the tutorial I'm following the tab bar is automatically visible. My window just looks blank, but when I run the program, the tab bar shows up. So how can I make connections to it?